# Import excel file and loop run for each row in Excel file

Tags: python, web-scraping, module

I have this code to scrape the results from google. If I have a list of terms I need to search in Excel/Csv format, how can I write the code to

- After import the excel file, search each row values  and print out the results for that row.
- Repeat for the next row value in the Excel file.

Here's my code. Please help with any solution you can think of

For example my Excel file just have 1 column and 3 values as below:
**List to search**
Defuse
Commercial
Ecommerce

```
from ecommercetools import seo
import csv
import pandas as pd

searching = input('What do you want to search?')
results = seo.get_serps(searching)

df = pd.DataFrame(results.head(20))  # Convert result into data frame.
df.to_csv("ScanOutput.csv",mode="a")
```

Thank you

I tried with several module but stuck somehow. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please provide sample data e.g. listtosearch, and a small sample of the dataframe.  Also provide a sample of what you expect the output to be.  As written there is insufficient information to help.

Comment: So the output should be like: (The data outcome will just show below existing ones)
Position   title       link
1              ABC        HTTP://values1search_result
2              DEF         HTTP://values2search_result

Answer (score 0):

If this is the content of your .csv file called file.csv:

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
k,l,m
```

then you can read it and loop row by row like so:

```
import csv

# read file.csv and print each row
with open('file.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

This answer doesn't use pandas (but csv which is simpler) which I think is ok until you don't have gigabytes of data or the data is very complex

Comment: Hi, after the loop to have the values for each row in Csv file, how can you make it search value 1 -> write on the data frame the Output of value 1 -> search value 2 -> write on the df Output value 2? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @Mike , your code will help read each row, but if I need one more action after reading it, how would I do that? For instance, put each value in the 'searching' function. Hope this helps